# Excel validation dropdown long list

Tags: excel, list, validation

Does excel dropdown validation list have a limit.

Trying to put the list of states but it doesn't show all of them:

> Source: Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado, Connecticut, Delaware, District of Columbia, Florida, Georgia, Hawaii, Idaho, Illinois, Indiana, Iowa, Kansas, Kentucky, Louisiana, Maine, Maryland, Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Montana, Nebraska, Nevada, New Hampshire, New Jersey, New Mexico, New York, North Carolina, North Dakota, Ohio, Oklahoma, Oregon, Pennsylvania, Rhode Island, South Carolina, South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Utah, Vermont, Virginia, Washington, West Virginia, Wisconsin, Wyoming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all 50 States in a column (you can hide the column), then allow a List and select the cells with the States

Comment: I hear an echo. Beat you by 3 seconds.  8P

Answer (score 1):

Put the list in a worksheet and reference that instead of putting the list in manually:

> There are limits to the number of items that will show in a data validation drop down list:
>
> The list can show up to show 32,767 items from a list on the worksheet.
>
> If you type the items into the data validation dialog box (a delimited list), the limit is 256 characters, including the separators.

From http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal08.html#itemlimit

Comment: Thanks for the info